# cUrl - Host can not be resolved while ping is working fine

Tags: php, curl, guzzle, php-curl

After running an apt upgrade and a restart of my ubuntu server, cUrl (via Guzzle) repots an error that the host cannot be resolved.

```
cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: xx.xx (see http:\/\/curl.haxx.se\/libcurl\/c\/libcurl-errors.html)
```

My code is

```
$client = new Client();
$response = $client->post("https://xx.xx?r=/center/api", [
            RequestOptions::HEADERS => [
                'X-Requested-With' => 'XMLHttpRequest'
            ]
        ]);
```

This happens randomly and with multiple domains. Meanwhile i was running pings for those domains on the terminal and they were working.

On StackOverflow and Google I could only find solutions that were adding the host to the hosts file but for me that seems to be not a real solution.

Comment: Check the /etc/nsswitch.conf file - maybe the error is there. In the past, most of my problems like this coming from the nsswitch.conf

Comment: @rebru nsswitch.conf workin fine, the error is still popping up randomly